# A public action method 'index​' was not found on controller in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action, public

I have action method as below with out any HTTP GET and POST mentioned on Action.

```
    public ActionResult Index(bool isTemplate = false)
    {
        ViewBag.isTemplate = isTemplate;
        return this.View("Index");
    }
```

For some strange reason, I am Getting below exception

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A public action method 'index​' was not found on controller 'Nalco.enVision.Web.Areas.Reporting.Controllers.ReportController'.
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Why am i getting this error intermittently?

Comment: How do you call this action? And what attributes do you have for the controller class?

Comment: I think you have too much on your return line.  Try shortening it to return View();

Comment: Are you calling it using the following url: `/reporting/report` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Index(bool isTemplate = false)    {
        ViewBag.isTemplate = isTemplate;
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that that `ActionResult` method is inside your `ReportController`, change your return statement to:

```
return View();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error because the pages/Action method I was calling required authentication so i just added the attribute above the methods as

```
[AllowAnonymous]
Public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're calling this Action, but I've encountered this issue when a View is NOT posting back to itself.

In other words, with your example you have a Controller called ReportController and a View called Index.cshtml.  If there is a different View, say Different.cshtml that has a form intended to post to Report/Index.cshtml like the following:

```
@Html.BeginForm("Index", "ReportController", FormMethod.Post)
```

then try posting back to the Action for Different, then RedirectToAction Index within the ReportController.
The code above would just become:

```
@Html.BeginForm()
```

See if this gets you past the "A public action method X was not found on controller Y"